# Kubernetes DaemonSet Permission Denied on mounted Volume - Docker in Docker dind

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I tried running simple DaemonSet on kube cluster - the Idea was that other kube pods would connect to that containers docker daemon (dockerd) and execute commands on it. (The other pods are Jenkins slaves and would have just env DOCKER_HOST point to 'tcp://localhost:2375'); In short the config looks like this:

dind.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: dind
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: dind
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: dind
    spec:
            #      tolerations:
            #      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
            #        effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
      - name: dind
        image: docker:18.05-dind
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 2000Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 500Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: dind-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker
      volumes:
        - name: dind-storage
          emptyDir: {}
```

Error message when running

```
mount: mounting none on /sys/kernel/security failed: Permission denied
Could not mount /sys/kernel/security.
AppArmor detection and --privileged mode might break.
mount: mounting none on /tmp failed: Permission denied
```

I took the idea from medium post that didn't describe it fully: https://medium.com/hootsuite-engineering/building-docker-images-inside-kubernetes-42c6af855f25 describing docker of docker, docker in docker and Kaniko

Comment: Have you tried to put `securityContext: privileged: true` in your `YAML` definition?

Answer (score 1):

found the solution

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: dind
spec:
    containers:
      - name: jenkins-slave
        image: gcr.io/<my-project>/myimg     # it has docker installed on it
        command: ['docker', 'run', '-p', '80:80', 'httpd:latest']
        resources:
            requests:
                cpu: 10m
                memory: 256Mi
        env:
          - name: DOCKER_HOST
            value: tcp://localhost:2375
      - name: dind-daemon
        image: docker:18.05-dind
        resources:
            requests:
                cpu: 20m
                memory: 512Mi
        securityContext:
            privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
          - name: docker-graph-storage
            mountPath: /var/lib/docker
    volumes:
      - name: docker-graph-storage
        emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: For those looking to the same answer and wondering what exactly is the solution - the key is "privileged: true". Also if you're running a customised dind image, you might need to make sure that dockerd is started in the pod - just "dockerd" suffice for local docker work on the same pod